# Is the set M satisfying the following property?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I wanted to ask whether I did the task correctly:

> **Task:** Let M be a set satisfying the following property P:
>   ”For every element x of M there is an element y of M such that x + y is an
>   element of M.”
>   Express the statement P using logical quantor, negate P and find a set which
>   fulfills P and one that does not.

My solution:

$$M := \{x: \exists y\in M \ \ \text{such that} \ \ x+y∈M\}$$

$$P: ∀x\in M ∃y\in M(x+y \in M)$$

Negation of $P$:  $∃x∈M∀y∈M(x+y∉M)$

A set that would fulfill such a property would be ℕ.

What would be a set of the important number sets that do not fulfill the property above?

Is it correct what I did?

Comment: I do not understand why I got a minus point... Okay I could format the text better but you could've just wrote me that and as I see the notation has changed in the edited version but the notation before is how I learnt it, that's why I do not understand the minus point. Plus I did the exercise myself and I just wanted a confirmation whether it is right or not..

Comment: When you ask to "define the set $M$", what do you mean? Which set $M$? Same question for $P$. Do you have to come up with such examples or are they given? I suppose the former, but the way you phrase it is ambiguous. On the other hand, your definition of $M$ is also not well defined. What are the elements of $M$? I can assume that you want to talk about sets of numbers of some kind, but this has to be stated explicitly somewhere, otherwise I might think you are adding glazed doughnuts!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will edit the question and you may understand what the exercise is and you may can answer whether I did it right!

Comment: I updated the task. If it is still not understandable, let me know! It is the original task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! Now the situation is much clearer; thanks for that edit.

Now, with regards to your answer... For a normal mathematician, your translation of the statement $P$ with logical symbols would be correct. However, the pedantic mathematician out there (or the logician) would argue that you could express $P$ in the following way. You consider a formal language consisting of a binary function symbol $+$ and a unary predicate (also called relation) symbol $M$; for a variable $x$, $M(x)$ would mean that "$x$ is in the set $M$". Then this same pedantic mathematician would argue that a correct translation of the statement $P$ to logical symbols (in the language $\{+, R\}$) would be given by $$\forall x \exists y (M(x) \to (M(y) \wedge M(x+y))).$$ If these concepts sound too alien and weird, you can safely ignore them; I'm assuming your professor wants to see the answer as the one you've given. Also, the negation of the statement is correct.

Finally, sets of numbers which would not satisfy such a property are given by singletons, for example. Indeed, consider the case of $M = \{1\}$; then clearly $M$ doesn't satisfy $P$, since $1+1 = 2 \notin M$. You can also consider finite sets like $\{1, 2, \dots, 665, 666\}$ or $\{\pi, \pi^2, \pi^3\}$ and these would not satisfy $P$ if we interpret $+$ as sum of integers in the first case or sum of real numbers in the second. However, if  we consider the set $\{0, 1\}$ and we interpret $+$ as addition of elements modulo $2$, then $\{0, 1\}$ would indeed satisfy $P$.

Comment: Thank your for concise answer!